# How to customize UIAlertController to add an image in the right part

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

This is what I am trying to achive. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPSaE.jpg But sadly the image is coming in the left part.

The code is

```
                                                  }];
    UIAlertAction *emailmember = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Email Member"
                                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                            [orderVC emailMember];
                                                        }];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_disclosure.png"];

    UIImageView* arrowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(410.0, 440.0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

    [arrowImageView setImage:image];


    [emailmember setValue:image forKey:@"image"];
```

Comment: UIAlertController doesn't support such customizations. Any attempt to do so is fragile and could break with any future iOS update.

Answer (score -1):

i have done that code using swift please modify using objective c

```
func load_image(_ urlString:String)
{
    let imgURL: URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: imgURL)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil && data != nil)
        {
            func display_image()

            {
                let prevImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 80, height: 100))
                prevImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                let spacer = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r"
                let titleData = "TEST"
                let previewController = UIAlertController(title: titleData, message: spacer, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SAVE", style: .default)
                { (UIAlertAction) in

                    self.arrayData.insert("Data inserted \(titleData)", at: 0)
                    self.testTableView .reloadData()

                }
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                previewController.addAction(saveAction)
                previewController.addAction(cancelAction)
                previewController.view.addSubview(prevImage)
                self.present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: display_image)
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```